# How to extract only characters and remove noises from such image in matlab

Tags: image, text-extraction, matlab-compiler

I have a binary image after using sobel operator as below:

[m11.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7lO4.jpg)

I want to extract only characters and remove noises from the image in MATLAB

Please help me with some example code

Thanks

Comment: What code have you written yourself to solve this problem? What errors and problems are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

Look up the stroke width transform. Writing can be detected because it contains a lot of equal-width even strokes, many at 90 degree angles to each other.

However as far as I know there isn't a Matlab package for the technique (there probably is one somewhere, if you hunt for it). It's rather an involved method.